# TinyXml append to xml file

Tags: append, tinyxml

I have been working on a project for a few months now and my main issue i am having right now is appending to an xml file. I can create the files no problem. But i want to be able to add more data. Basically use it like a small database.

The code included is only a small part of the whole program but i believe it is in here i need help with to figure out the process to append to the file. Each element takes user input without any issues. but when they go to write a second Horse tot he file is wipes out the old one and make a whole new file.

Any suggestions on how to append would be great

```
void WriteThisHorseToFile(char* horseName, char* horseMother, char* horseFather, char* horseHeight, 
                      char* horseOwner, char* horseAge, char* horseWins, char* horseMarkings, char* horseNotes)  
{  

TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( decl );  

TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "Horses" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( root );

TiXmlElement * element2 = new TiXmlElement( "Name" );  
root->LinkEndChild( element2 );  

TiXmlText * text2 = new TiXmlText(horseName);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text2 );  

TiXmlElement * element3 = new TiXmlElement( "Mother" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element3 );  

TiXmlText * text3 = new TiXmlText(horseMother);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text3 );  

TiXmlElement * element4 = new TiXmlElement( "Father" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element4 );  

TiXmlText * text4 = new TiXmlText(horseFather);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text4 );  

TiXmlElement * element5 = new TiXmlElement( "Height" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element5 );  

TiXmlText * text5 = new TiXmlText(horseHeight);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text5 ); 

TiXmlElement * element6 = new TiXmlElement( "Owner" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element6 );  

TiXmlText * text6 = new TiXmlText(horseOwner);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text6 );

TiXmlElement * element7 = new TiXmlElement( "Age" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element7 );  

TiXmlText * text7 = new TiXmlText(horseAge);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text7 );

TiXmlElement * element8 = new TiXmlElement( "Wins" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element8 );  

TiXmlText * text8 = new TiXmlText(horseWins);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text8 );

TiXmlElement * element9 = new TiXmlElement( "Markings" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element9 );  

TiXmlText * text9 = new TiXmlText(horseMarkings);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text9 );

TiXmlElement * element10 = new TiXmlElement( "Notes" );  
element2->LinkEndChild( element10 );  

TiXmlText * text10 = new TiXmlText(horseNotes);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text10 );

dump_to_stdout( &doc );
doc.SaveFile("demo2.xml"); 

PressEnter();
}
```

Comment: So no one able to suggest a way of do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry first time posting and just getting used to layout of site.

How i solved the appending issue for the xml file.
turns out it was quite simple. I will make use the example above.

it is not the cleanest of code but the example still applies.
Now that it is working i can tidy up the code a bit.

I just hope this helps other see how it can be done.

```
void WriteThisHorseToFile(char* horseName, char* horseMother, char* horseFather, char* horseHeight, 
                  char* horseOwner, char* horseAge, char* horseWins, char* horseMarkings, char* horseNotes)  

TiXmlDocument doc;
doc.LoadFile ("horses.xml");


TiXmlElement* root = doc.FirstChildElement( "Horses" );
if ( root )
{

TiXmlElement * element2 = new TiXmlElement( "Name" );  
root->LinkEndChild( element2 );  

TiXmlText * text2 = new TiXmlText(horseName);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text2 );  

//add as many child links as you wish :D

}

else 

{  

TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( decl );  

TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "Horses" );  
doc.LinkEndChild( root );

TiXmlElement * element2 = new TiXmlElement( "Name" );  
root->LinkEndChild( element2 );  

TiXmlText * text2 = new TiXmlText(horseName);  
element2->LinkEndChild( text2 ); 

//add as many child links as you wish :D 

}
```